# What plan should white play with?

Tags: planning

It's black's turn. What plan should white use so as to confirm it's win? Thanks!

```
 [fen "r1b5/ppkn3R/3p2p1/8/N2b1B2/8/P1P2PPP/5RK1 w - - 0 50"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White is an exchange up with a much safer king and more active / developed pieces. There are many ways to win. The most straightforward here is to exchange pieces where and queen a pawn.

Comment: Things got pretty nasty when black moved pawn in order to kill white's knight. But the pair of rooks was extremely helpful, hunting in pairs and white won eventually. Thanks for your response anyway!

Comment: If black threatens the knight with b5 then Nb2 saves the knight which can be usefully redirected to d3

Comment: you probably missed the bishop at d4

Comment: If b5 then c3 Bf6 Nc5 saves the knight

Comment: Ankit, @IanBush you are both right. In the original picture I missed that the piece on d4 is a black bishop and not a pawn. I've edited the original post to replace the picture with a diagram which, at least for my old eyes, is easier to read properly.